# Create additional "upload from file" button in header of Detail Grid Purchase Receipt in Acumatica

Tags: customization, acumatica

Is it possible to add new additional button "Upload from file" in header of Document Detail transaction in Purchase Receipt like the following screenshot ?

[image]

I want to implement the same way like in screen Purchase Order, please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

Does anyone knows how to provide this goal ?

Thanks.

Comment: Should be the same approach as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644489/3929852)

Comment: Thanks @RuslanDev, it was worked in my instance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I create an extension of POReceiptEntry, and use the following codes:

   ```
   public class POReceiptEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<POReceiptEntry>
   {
       #region Event Handlers
       [PXViewName(Messages.POReceiptLine)]
       [PXImport(typeof(POReceipt))]
       [PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(POReceiptLine.allowComplete))]
   public PXSelect<POReceiptLine, Where<POReceiptLine.receiptType, Equal<Current<POReceipt.receiptType>>,
                   And<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<Current<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>>>,
                   OrderBy<Asc<POReceiptLine.receiptType, Asc<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Asc<POReceiptLine.lineNbr>>>>> Transactions;
       #endregion
   }
   ```
2. And then Validate and Publish my customize project.
3. Enable the "Auto Upload" of Layout Editor screen. Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

4. Validate and publish the customization to implement the customization